# How to write a sql update query for below condition?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, plsql, sql-update

I have 2 tables. First is employee table and has (id,emp_num,name,address_id,text) columns.
Second is address table with (adress_id,emp_num,adress,state) columns.

Now when I am inserting/updating a new record into employee table, I also want to update TEXT column for all other entries for that emp_num who are from the same state.

EMPLOYEE table:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7KlI.png)

Address table:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Py6Bh.png)

I am trying to do a update like below:
update employee set id_text='ABCABC' where id = 'ID1';
some other update query
after that employee table should look like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQtmY.png)
(note: text field is updated for ID1 and ID4)

Thanks

Comment: You have established a {1,1}:{1,1} relation by providing both tables with emp_num and address_id? I.e. there is exactly one address row per employee row and one employee row per address row?

Comment: Read Littlefoot's comment under their answer. It seems you are trying to solve some problem here that should be solved otherwise. Give an example of your data and tell us what that text shall contain before and after the updates. We can probably give you advice then how to get to a better design.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Added sample data, have any advice?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: This looks horrible. How can an employee table contain two rows for the same employee (same emp_num)? This should not be possible. Normalize that table. Then you have the address_id in the employee table and the emp_num in the address table. Make your mind up: Do you want to reference other table's rows by ID or by natural key? And must you double-link (address to employee, employee to address)? What relation do you want anyhow? 1:n? m:n? or 1:1?

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE employee e
SET e.text = (SELECT a.state FROM address a WHERE a.address_id = e.address_id)
WHERE e.emp_num IN (SELECT a.emp_num FROM address a WHERE a.state = (SELECT a.state FROM address a WHERE a.address_id = e.address_id));
```

Comment: text and state are two different columns with different data and I don't want to set TEXT column's values as STATE.

Answer (score 0):

To me, it looks as if you need a row-level trigger which fires whenever you insert or update a row in `employee` table; using `:new.address_id`, fetch `state` from `address` table and put it into employee's `text` column:

```
create or replace trigger trg_biu_emp
  before insert or update on employee
  for each row
begin
  select a.state
    into :new.text
    from address a
    where a.address_id = :new.address_id;
end;
/
```

Comment: Yep, it looks like they want a trigger. But if I read it correctly, they want to update address.text for all rows that match the employee's address's state.

Comment: On a second thought (reading the question, that is), @Thorsten, I'd say that you're right. On the other hand, I'd also say that EMPLOYEE table shouldn't be updated at all. If they want to know in which STATE that ADDRESS is, join two tables and get that information. If TEXT column's only purpose is to reflect ADDRESS.STATE, I'd rather drop it.

Comment: You are right, this looks suspiciously like redundancy. If they want to update the addresses with some text like 'There are 28 employees in this same state now', they should rather not store this, but get the number from a query. I agree, it seems the OP wants to do things here, they probably shouldn't do.

Comment: @Littlefoot, TEXT and STATE are different colums with different data. I don't  want to update TEXT column with STATE, I want to update TEXT column of all entries for that emp_num from employee table that belongs to same STATE from address

Comment: It would be easier to understand if you posted sample data which illustrate what you have, and what you want to get as result.

Comment: added sample table data

Comment: OK, that's what you have. What is desired result? When is it supposed to happen? As one-time action (so you'd write UPDATE statement), or any time you modify EMPLOYEE table, or ...?

Comment: @Littlefoot, So when I have a update for specific employee id for change in text field, I also want to update that text field for all the address from same state of that same employees. I have Something like "UPDATE EMPLOYEE SET TEXT='ABCABC' WHERE ID='ID1';" --For this, I need addition query which will update the ids with ID1 and ID4(since both are from same state).

Comment: You said that. I'd like to *see it*. Post the result, literally (as a screenshot, if you don't have anything else).

Comment: @Littlefoot, see the edited question. I added screenshot